# Difficult PHP Nested Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, nested, preg-match-all

Given the following string:

```
{start} SubPattern1 {end} 
....
{start} SubPattern2 {end}
....
{start} {start}SubPattern3{end} {end}
```

I need to find the regular expression that gives me the following result:

```
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $result);
```

> print_r($result);

```
array(2
    0 => array(3
        0 => {start} SubPattern1 {end}
        1 => {start} SubPattern2 {end}
        2 => {start} {start}SubPattern3{end} {end}
    )
    1 => array(3
        0 => SubPattern1 
        1 => SubPattern2 
        2 => {start}SubPattern3{end} 
    )
)
```

Thank you!

**Edit**

For visual purpose I wrote a multiline string. But I need that the expression works even if all the text is in a single line string. eg:

> {start}SubPattern1{end}{start}SubPattern2{end}{start}{start}SubPattern3{end}{end}

Comment: Thank you! Any attempts?

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been marked as duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match {start} and {end} and use a capturing group and use recursion for the pattern:

```
{start}((?:(?:(?!{(?:start|end)}).)+|(?R))*){end}
```

For example:

```
$string = <<<DATA
{start} SubPattern1 {end} 
{start} SubPattern2 {end}
{start} {start}SubPattern3{end} {end}
DATA;

preg_match_all('/{start}((?:(?:(?!{(?:start|end)}).)+|(?R))*){end}/', $string, $result);
print_r($result);
```

**Explanation**

- `{start}` Match literally
- `(` Start capturing group

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?:` Non capturing group

      - `(?!{(?:start|end)}).` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not {start} or {end}. If that is the case, match any character.
    - `)+|(?R)` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times or `|` recurses the entire pattern
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close capturing group
- `{end}` - Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VMNoZt/1/)

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {start} SubPattern1 {end}
            [1] => {start} SubPattern2 {end}
            [2] => {start} {start}SubPattern3{end} {end}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  SubPattern1 
            [1] =>  SubPattern2 
            [2] =>  {start}SubPattern3{end} 
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/KY5cD)

Comment: Can you add explanation about recursive regex ? i am trying my head around it from last half hour. it will be helpful if you can. Thanks in advance

Comment: @CodeManiac I have added an explanation.

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's works well. But the pattern doesn't match when a curly bracket is present in the sub-pattern. eg: `{start} Pattern{1} {end}` <--- doesn't match. I need to match anything in between `{start}{end}`. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @JorgeLuis I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird that`s simply perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JorgeLuis You are welcome, glad it works for your. My advice would be to show in / add to your question what you have tried if in the future you want to ask another question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this**

```
^{start}(.*){end}$
```

- `^` - Start of string.
- `{start}` - Matches `{start}`.
- `(.*)` - Matches anything except new line. (capturing group).
- `{end}` - Matches `{end}`.
- `$` - End of the string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ULlDM/2/)

Comment: Thanks! But that only works if the patterns are in different lines. I need that the expression works even if the string is in a single line. I'll do the aclaration in the original post.

Comment: @JorgeLuis look at it https://regex101.com/r/8ULlDM/3

Comment: that's so close, but not working in the last nested pattern. Thanks again.